# Trimmer Capacitor/Inductor stability

Tags: trimmer

I am considering using either a trimmer capacitor or inductor combination with the other fixed valued component to create LC tuned filter for 1MHz.

I want the system's resonant frequency to remain stable over the temperature and time.

What parameters should I look for?

Also, looking at the datasheet below, 
[Coilcraft Variable Inductor Datashseet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/597/uni10-463412.pdf)

It states LMin, Lnom, and Lmax.

Do the three parameters above man the value of the inductor when it is at it's full inductance(when it's completely turned?)?, Or as I turn, the inductance moves from only LMin to LMax?

1180 nH rated inductor's LMin is 1010nH and LMax is 1340nH. Does that mean that one end of the turn is 1010nH and the other end of the turn is 1340nH? or does that mean the range of inductance at maximum turn?

Comment: The stability rating?

Comment: Nothing remains stable so, how close to remaining stable do you want and please don't say as close as you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1180 nH rated inductor's LMin is 1010nH and LMax is 1340nH. Does that
>   mean that one end of the turn is 1010nH and the other end of the turn
>   is 1340nH? or does that mean the range of inductance at maximum turn?

It tells me that for the 143-17J12L inductor, the inductance is 830 nH with the core removed. Lmin has note 3 associated with it and this tells you that the inductance specified is with the core halfway out top of form.

Lmax might be the maximum inductance you might see with the core halfway out top of form.

From these I would estimate that the inductance will start at around 830 nH and be typically 1180 nH with the core halfway. It might increase a further 350 nH with the core fully inserted.

As for your choice of nominally 1 uH to tune at 1 MHz requires about 25 nF. Given also that the coil you have chosen is about 20 milli ohms, the Q you will get is going to be about between about 150 and 300 so it's going to be quite difficult to keep stable against temperature drifts.

Comment: I am not familiar in determining the value of Q. I am considering lowering the Q by inserting a small series resistor. Around what range do you recommend?

Comment: For a parallel tuned circuit with resistance in series with the inductor, Q = \$\dfrac{1}{R}\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\$ - look up Q factor on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't bash it, an adjustable inductor or capacitor will maintain its adjusted value, being only affected by temperature.

Components that are intended to be long term stable will have a tempco specified for them. There *are* ranges of inductors and capacitors made with tempcos that will offset each other, so keeping the LC product nominally constant as temperature changes both. Your task is to read the data sheets to find matching types. Some types of capacitor are headlined as having 'compensating tempcos' in the data sheet, google can find them (capax, presidio, yuden ...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 1010nH and 1340nh are the ends of the adjustable range.  If you look at note 3 they say the 1010nH end is with the core half way out.  This is the range they recommend you stay within.  You see they say with the core removed you could get to 830nH.  They don't recommend you run it between 830 and 1010nH.  Perhaps because if the core is more than half way it less stable.